# Кодировка данных в phpmyadmin

Tags: php, перекодировка, mysql

Создал БД в phpmyadmin, через скрипт туда записываю данные, однако там русские слова отображаются неправильно. Какая кодировка должна по умолчанию быть в скрипте и в майадмине? Где и как проще сменить кодировку? Предпочел бы сменить в майадмине, но сойдет и изменение в скрипте на ту, что стоит в майадмине по умолчанию.

Comment: Не могу пока решить проблему... Сначала надо в базу заносить данные, потом смотреть их через майадмин. При этом запрос имеет вид INSERT into users values ("Текст"), кодировка функцией mb_detect_encoding определяется как UTF-8. В базе меняю кодировку (сравнение у них это называется) на UTF8_unicode_li для базы, таблицы и колонки, но данные все равно отображаются не правильно. Что еще можно попробовать?

Comment: а на выводе у вас тоже UTF-8 или выводите с другой кодировкой?
Попробуйте кодировку сайта поменять на UTF-8 или выводимые значения конвертировать на кодировку вашего сайта.

Comment: В самом админе выводится неправильно или на сайте при запросе?

Comment: Вот именно в админе неправильно. Кстати, кодировка в php изначально все-таки ср1251, как выяснилось (функция mb_detect_encoding оказалась не права). Поэтому изменял все в базе именно на нее, но в админе все равно некорректно отображается.

Answer (score 1):

в пхп это:
в самом начале скрипта - `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'ваша кодировка в бд'");`

в мускуле - заходите в параметры бд и там будет опция смены кодировки.

Comment: и когда база разрастётся - наслаждайтесь её тормозами, ага!

Answer (score 1):

если есть доступ к файлу настроек MySQL сервера my.ini, то всё просто:

```
[client]
# кодировка в которой сервер "работает" с клиентом (с Вашим скриптом в частности)
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
# кодировка в которой сервер "работает" с консолью (win+r -> cmd -> ...) В винде это cp866
default-character-set=cp866

[mysqld]
# кодкировка, в которой сервер хранит информацию
character-set-server=utf8
```

Если все файлы скриптов и всё-всё-всё будет сохранено в utf8, то будет Вам счастье. Надеюсь помог.

П.С. Просто чтобы Вы знали говорю: то, что в майАдмине названо сравнением не связано с тем, в какой кодировке сервер БД будет возвращать информацию. Это всего лишь тип способа сравнения строк. например, если задано сравнение utf8_general_ci, то MySQL будет думать что строки "mysql" и "MySQL" равны. Если же установлено сравнение к примеру utf8_bin, то эти же строки сервером будут расценены как разные.

Answer (score 0):

ALTER DATABASE `databasename` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
Собственно, 1 запросом всё решается.
п.с. Для веб-разработки народ "между собой договорился" использовать именно utf8.

Comment: Никто ни о чем не договаривался, использую win 1251 и никаких проблем.

Comment: не дай вам Бог в win1251 с XMLHttpRequest столкнуться :) с iconv()'ами замучаетесь!

Answer (score 0):

[client]
кодировка в которой сервер "работает" с клиентом (с Вашим скриптом в частности)
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
кодировка в которой сервер "работает" с консолью (win+r -> cmd -> ...) В винде это cp866
default-character-set=cp866

[mysqld]
кодкировка, в которой сервер хранит информацию
character-set-server=utf8

для linux - В файл "mysql.chf" , который находится в etc/mysql и тд.. и всё работает.